# AngularJS Direct Upload to Google Cloud Storage Error

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload file size higher than 32MB to GCS directly from AngularJS

I could successfully upload to `Blobstore` when the file size is less than 32MB using the code given below.

```
$http.post(uploadUrl, $scope.formData, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    transformRequest: angular.identity
});
```

When I try to upload the file using url `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/filename`, I got the following error.

`Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

When I remove flag `withCredentials: true` used in http post, I got response as 403, no error details are given.

I have set the cors as mentioned for the upload bucket
`[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "POST", "HEAD"], "origin": ["http://localhost:8088"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]`

How to enable `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` flag in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this while continuing to use the blobstore, rather than switching to Cloud Storage. Google documents that process fairly well. Warning: it sounds to me like Google is supporting this as a legacy feature, but recommends using Could Storage instead. I have not done this personally, but it sounds like [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/#Signed-URLs) may be the answer there.

If you want to continue with the blobstore, as I have, instructions for the server-side setup in Java are [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob). You should find similar instructions for other languages at similar URLs. :)

The tricky part that I didn't understand at first: the direct upload request does its thing, then makes a call directly to your server with information about the upload, then uses your server's response as the response back to the client. So for example, you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your server's upload handler, and it will be added to the response from the direct upload link.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for the response. I tried signed url as suggested I got the same error. Download is successful but not upload. For uploading through blobstore, I got a different error, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344261/gcs-heap-error-when-file-of-higher-size-was-uploaded.
I could not use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header successfully, modifying httpProvider default header `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';` with `withCredentials: false` setting not helped much. Could you guide me on using the header?

Comment: You need to set that header on the _response_ sent from your _server_, no the request from your client. So in your Java code (which I see is your language of choice from the other question you linked), you could use `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`.

Comment: Hi @Eric, I can stick to your first two solutions. That really helps!